# Anonymous VM is too much high

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, didreceivememorywarning

I am working on one application and it crashed without any warning. In application we are downloading many images from server and caching images locally. I am doing app analysis using instruments . In that, i have noticed "Anonymous VM" is too much high. I have attached screen shot for my situations. Does app crashes because of this ? Please help me to come out from this.[image]

Comment: Also trying to understand the right course of action here. How can I see what kind of data is being allocated into anonymous VM?  I suspect it's images...